# What is an analysis dictionary or operator in compressive sensing?

Tags: discrete-signals, matrix, compressive-sensing, reconstruction

I am doing research on compressive sensing. I am new in this field. I  read several papers regarding analysis dictionaries.

Here are some papers that I have read so far:

https://www.hindawi.com/journals/tswj/2014/852978/

https://www.matec-conferences.org/articles/matecconf/pdf/2018/18/matecconf_ijcaet-isampe2018_01061.pdf

https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/7374920

What I do not understand is if I have

$Ω ∈ \mathbb{R}^{P\times M} $ where $x$ is the raw signal, $x ∈ \mathbb{R}^{M \times 1} $

- What is an analysis dictionary (AD,) and an example of an analysis dictionary?
- How can we obtain $AD ∈ \mathbb{R}^{P \times 1}$

Comment: It seems to me that the papers you have read so far are not very authoritative. Why did you  chose them?

Comment: I read IEEE proceeding that stated Greedy Analysis Pursuit has better performance rather than any methods in Greedy class, therefore I am interested in GAP